# What is the change in vision and measurement between curved space and flat space, especially for measuring cosmic background radiation?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, cosmic-microwave-background, cosmological-constant

In a curved space, the light bends as it travels and acts like it is going through a lens. In a (positively) curved universe, a small object appears larger. If we know the actual size of an object, like a spot in the microwave backgroun temperature due to sound waves, the size it appears lensed on the sky tells us the curvature of the universe.

The curvature decides the fate of the universe. What is curving space and lensing light is the matter itself. The more mass the universe has the greater its curvature. If the universe has enough mass, gravitational attraction can halt the expansion and cause the universe to collapse.

By measuring the curvature of the universe in the size of spots in the microwave background temperature maps, we determine the ultimate fate of the universe.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.